# the fastest way to create vector z, such that z[i] = 1/(1+i)

Tags: python, numpy

I need create a vector z in numpy such that z[i] = 1/(1+i). Is there faster way to do it then in the code below?

```
import numpy as np
n = 10000
z = np.zeros(n)
for i in xrange(n):
    z[i] = 1.0/(1 + i)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quickest way:

```
z = 1.0/np.arange(1, n+1)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
z = np.arange(n)
z = 1/(1+z)
```

Comment: yes, it should be faster. The only thing you need to correct is write 1.0/(1+z), otherwise there will be mostly zeros